# java gson - Check if JsonElement is string or JsonObject

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to make an API backward-compatible by checking a value.

I have to determine if one of the parameters is a `string` or a `JsonObject`.

This is what I tried:

```
if (oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().isJsonObject()) {
                  deviceToClean.addProperty("deviceId", oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
              } else if(oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
                  deviceToClean.addProperty("deviceId", oDevices.get(i).getAsString());
              }
```

When I send a JsonObject to the API, I get the following error:

```
This is not a JSON Primitive.
```

How I can check whether `oDevices.get(i)` is a json object or a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are always getting the value as primitive.

Change this:

```
if (oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().isJsonObject()) {
```

to

```
if (oDevices.get(i).isJsonObject()) {
```

I would also change this:

```
if(oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {
```

To this:

```
if(oDevices.get(i).isJsonPrimitive() && oDevices.get(i).getAsJsonPrimitive().isString()) {

// ----------------^ check if it's a json primitive before getting its value
```

Comment: Thanks @BackSlash. I thought the `isJsonObject()` method does not exists on a simple `JsonElement`.